# Using `ngModel` in conjunction with radio input to display or hide a section

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, radio-button

I am building an user interface where the user can create two types of content namely **LINK** and **MESSAGE**.

I would have used an inbuilt solution for example the Segment component in Ionic but that is not possible due to the design requirements.

What I am doing is I have two radio input

```
<input [(ngModel)]="notificationCreateType" type="radio" id="notification_type_link" name="notificationType" value="0" class="custom-radio" />

<input [(ngModel)]="notificationCreateType" checked type="radio" id="notification_type_message" name="notificationType" value="1" class="custom-radio" />
```

Value 0 is for link and 1 is for message.

```
            <div *ngIf="notificationCreateType == '0'">
                ... stuffs here
            </div>


            <div *ngIf="notificationCreateType == '1'">
                ... stuffs here
            </div>
```

It seems to be working fine when either of the radio options are selected, but doesn't work initially when the page loads and an radio option is already checked.

`[(ngModel)]="notificationCreateType"` definitely uses the value of the radio input and set the `notificationCreateType` to it, though it doesn't do the same when the input is already checked by setting a `checked` attribute

What I would like to do is either have `ngModel` respect the input's `checked` property or even better would be I can set `notificationCreateType`'s initial value in the component's ts file which is the used to check the radio input automatically in the template.

Is that even possible because I went through many docs, including official Ionic and Angular docs still found nothing in detail about Radio inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `checked` attribute from the template. It's useless because Angular overwrites the checked value with the starting value of `notificationCreateType`.  So you would just have

```
<input [(ngModel)]="notificationCreateType" type="radio"
        name="notificationType" value="0"/>

<input [(ngModel)]="notificationCreateType" type="radio"
        name="notificationType" value="1"/>
```

Then in the component class, just set the starting value:

```
public notificationCreateType = '1';
```

Angular will take care of checking the default radio button for you.

Comment: Wow! This just worked so beautifully. 

I am excluding the `public` keyword and still does work, I hope that wouldn't cause any problems in the future. 

Thanks !

Comment: `public` is assumed unless `private` is specified, so I don't think it will cause problems.